# TCP/IP Exception when using WCF Discovery

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, discovery

We have the following code...

### DiscoveryService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDiscoveryService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PrintHello();
}

public class DiscoveryService : IDiscoveryService
{
    public void PrintHello()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

### Server.cs

```
    private void InitializeDiscovery()
    {
        Uri baseAddress = DiscoveryHelper.AvailableTcpBaseAddress;
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof (DiscoveryService), baseAddress);
        host.EnableDiscovery();
        host.Open();
    }
```

### Client.cs

```
    private void DiscoverAddressClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndpointAddress address =  DiscoveryHelper.DiscoverAddress<IDiscoveryService>();
        Binding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

        IDiscoveryService proxy = ChannelFactory<IDiscoveryService>.CreateChannel(binding, address);
        proxy.PrintHello();

        (proxy as ICommunicationObject).Close();
    }
```

Now, this code seems to work up until the point where we modify anything having to do with the Service Contract, at which point we get a TCP Exception, Error Code 10061 (Connection Actively Refused). However, we cant figure out who is refusing, or why. If we try to revert our code to a previous state, when it was working, we can't, it simply refuses to work after (it seems) we add / remove things from the project.

Every time I build I clean first. We're also following the [instructions posted here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335779.aspx).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I will begin by stating that I'm not all that familiar with WCF Discovery....though I may implement it in our new server stack.  But one thing I do not see here is the presence of a proxy server in what you present here.

As I understand it from what I've read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456787.aspx) your WCF service will basically register it's presence to a proxy server running on the network.  Your client will then 'discover' your service server via the DiscoveryProxy server.  That may be the piece of the plumbing you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You current implementation of the server will close down the server as soon as the InitializeDiscovery Method is complete because your host only has function scope and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector unless you keep a reference somewhere else.